# Unexpected $code (T_VARIABLE) error in php

Tags: php, wordpress, download

I have a code

```
$code = get_field('x_download');
```

where $code will get a number value say 192

now when i do

```
echo do_shortcode('email-download download_id="$code" contact_form_id="2"]');
```

i'm unable to get value of $code i.e 192 in download_id
I'm sure something is wrong with my syntax

Answer (score 0):

Replace your line with this:

```
 do_shortcode("email-download download_id='$code' contact_form_id='2']");
```

Single quotes will not replace your PHP variable with value, instead it prints the variable as it is. Double quotes will do the replacement.

Comment: echo do_shortcode('email-download download_id=".$code." contact_form_id="2"]');

Comment: You cannot pass variables to shortcodes, only static values. Variables should be incorporated inside your shortcode

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as shown below

```
<?php  $code = get_field('ebooks_download');                            

echo do_shortcode('[email-download download_id='.get_field('ebooks_download').' contact_form_id="1420"]'); ?>
```